# Check if textfields were edited?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitextfield

I have a `UITextField` in each cell of my tableview.  I want to set a BOOL for if any text was edited in any textfield so I can prompt user to save later on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One simple approach is to set a tag for each of your UITextFields, and have a BOOL array with indexes matching the tags, named `editedTextFields`. Then, implement the method from the UITextFieldDelegate protocol:

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
```

Inside of it, using `textField.tag` to find out which UITextField has been edited, you can then set the BOOL array at the equivalent position to YES.

Answer (score 0):

Use `UITextFieldDelegate` and implements :

```
- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
```

Comment: That does not actually mean that anything changed.  They may have entered the field and left it without changing it.

Comment: you can check & compare the contents.

Answer (score 0):

You can try UITextField's delegate solve this problem. Have a try.

Comment: Well,you can try like this:if(UITextField.text!=nil) {NSLog(@"You should save it!"); }

Comment: Great! Edit your answer and put that in there. :)